# Row conditional formatting PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I need solution for rows conditional formatting (background) based on time now and time difference, before 48 hours, 84
For example:
 if in cell is today's date and time 13:00 /background color =#ffffff
 if in cell value is -48 hours different color
if in cell value is -84 different color.
Here is what I have

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "test");
    if (!$con) {
        die("Database Connection failed".mysqli_error());
    } else {
        $db_select = mysqli_select_db($con, 'test2');
        if (!$db_select) {
            die("Database selection failed".mysqli_error());
        } else {
        }
    }

$records = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER by user_Name");
$timenow = new DateTime();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing='1'>
    <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Last Contact</th>
    </tr>



<?php

if ($records) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
        $calc = $timenow - $row['date'];
        if ($calc > 12000) {
            $rowClass = "oldOrder";
        } else {
            $rowClass = "normalOrder";
        }
        echo '<tr class="'.$rowClass.'"><td>';
        echo $row['user_name'] . '';
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['Device_ID'] . '';
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['Last_Contact'] . '';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
}

?>
    <a href=”rowClass.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
</table>
```

Field in DB date is additional column that is set as DATETIME
I keep getting error

Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int in bla/bal line 50 that is this part

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    $calc = $timenow - $row['date'];
    if ($calc > 3) {
        $rowClass = "oldOrder";
    } else {
        $rowClass = "normalOrder";
```

Comment: Funny; you're querying as `ORDER by user_Name` but then later on, you're using `$row['user_name']` with all lower-case letters. That could be an issue here. Check for errors on the query, you're not doing that.

Comment: The connection error function you used is incorrect, you need to use is shown here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all the time information in the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format, using the [time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function in PHP and the [UNIX_TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function in MySQL  and work this way:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test" 'test2');

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $con->connect_error);
}

$records = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS u_date FROM test2 ORDER by user_Name");
$timenow = time();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing='1'>
    <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Last Contact</th>
    </tr>

<?php

if ($records) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
        $calc = $timenow - $row['u_date'];
        if ($calc > 12000) {
            $rowClass = "oldOrder";
        } else {
            $rowClass = "normalOrder";
        }
        echo '<tr class="'.$rowClass.'"><td>';
        echo $row['user_name'] . '';
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['Device_ID'] . '';
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['Last_Contact'] . '';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
}

?>
    <a href="rowClass.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</table>
```

Comment: `mysqli_error()` that function requires a database connection.

Comment: The connection error function you used is incorrect, as did the OP.

Comment: Also don't copy the whole thing over to your answer.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner thank you for pointing it out. I was focusing on the date problem, I'll correct the answer

Comment: `” ”` < I just spotted those now at the end for their code; the curly quotes should be regular as `"`. This whole thing is growing bigger; bit of a mess on the OP's part to start with.

Answer (score -1):

You need to compare apples to apples.
If your MySQL date field is of type date/datetime, you can just pass it as argument to DateTime and compare the objects:

```
$dateToCompare = new \DateTime("-3 days"); // 3 days ago
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    if ($dateToCompare > (new \DateTime($row['date']))) {
        $rowClass = "oldOrder";
    } else {
        $rowClass = "normalOrder";
```